# Can I compile Python on my PC, load it to an ESP32 and run it?

Tags: esp32, python

As a follow-up from [Can I retrieve a Python program from an ESP32?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/can-i-retrieve-a-python-program-from-an-esp32), I would like to make things a little more difficult for those who would steal my code (I do realize that I cannot prevent it).

Can I compile Python on my PC, load it to an ESP32 and run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [forum post](https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=2334), it is possible to include precompiled scripts (in a `modules` directory at build time) in the flash image. This requires the config `FROZEN_MPY_DIR`.

It is also possible to cross-compile using **mpy-cross**, but it looks like this requires some micropython source code changes (`#define MICROPY_PERSISTENT_CODE_LOAD (1)`), and also what looks like a bugfix in emitglue.c.

Although you don't save much code space, it looks like it is also possible to omit the compiler - although really I think simpler would be to omit the repl so there is no trivial software interface to the hardware.

The reference used was 2 years old, so there is a good chance that the state-of-the-art has moved on since then.

Comment: I note that that is MicroPython. I had originally planned to use full blown Python, but am slowly coming round to the idea of MicroPython. Good answer. Thanks. If/when I get time to try it out, I will report back

Comment: maybe you shouldn't be so worried about people wanting to steal a upython code?